# Lavaan in R with very small values

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am trying to run a `lavaan` structural equation model to identify change between two time points.

I have the following data set:

```
structure(list(COG_T1 = c(0.0010333, 0.00105981, 0.00113736, 
0.001108715, 0.00104864, 0.00110772, 0.00109096, 0.00109855, 
0.00104169, 0.00112465, 0.001096525, 0.000985059, 0.001098955, 
0.001069465, 0.00105376, 0.00106878, 0.00110388, 0.00108702, 
0.001162835, 0.001070955, 0.0010971, 0.00111695, 0.001060525, 
0.00108797, 0.00103262, 0.001117605, 0.001061707, 0.001156365, 
0.00104431, 0.00109114, 0.001053765, 0.001045395, 0.00106441, 
0.00108481, 0.0011145, 0.001095115, 0.001099075, 0.001057, 0.001096125, 
0.00109696, 0.001064795, 0.00108024, 0.00102137, 0.001103185, 
0.00111948, 0.001110965, 0.00103784, 0.00104419, 0.00101302, 
0.00108785, 0.001098765, 0.001052415, 0.0010976, 0.001064385, 
0.001129705, 0.001076575, 0.001049785, 0.00103181, 0.001078155, 
0.001129015, 0.001024814, 0.00109171, 0.001007862, 0.001099885, 
0.00109162, 0.001060665, 0.00106572, 0.00106803, 0.00113409, 
0.001052505, 0.001138575, 0.00108723, 0.001046765, 0.001090765
), COG_T2 = c(0.00106309, 0.00106822, 0.001052205, 0.001106125, 
0.001060125, 0.00106945, 0.001092695, 0.00107696, 0.001063425, 
0.001116725, 0.00105891, 0.001054205, 0.00109295, 0.00109387, 
0.00101807, 0.001066195, 0.001120295, 0.001111565, 0.001088595, 
0.00102183, 0.0010934, 0.00111935, 0.00105371, 0.00108314, 0.0011006, 
0.001079585, 0.001127775, 0.001140825, 0.00106203, 0.001118035, 
0.00103535, 0.00099512, 0.001078955, 0.00108867, 0.0010789, 0.001030445, 
0.00106243, 0.001028545, 0.00108679, 0.00105624, 0.001110145, 
0.00107318, 0.00106523, 0.001103515, 0.00112404, 0.001064455, 
0.001040425, 0.001059305, 0.00106362, 0.001079395, 0.00107183, 
0.0010652, 0.00106983, 0.00111722, 0.00114111, 0.001059649, 0.001029902, 
0.001062825, 0.001102155, 0.001122135, 0.00103623, 0.00108648, 
0.001081035, 0.001110075, 0.001039397, 0.001057715, 0.0010338, 
0.001071455, 0.001072065, 0.001032233, 0.00111996, 0.00106407, 
0.0010693, 0.001104395)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-74L))
```

plotted:

```
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)

id <- factor(1:length(DF$COG_T1)) 
plotdattemp <- data.frame(DF$COG_T1, DF$COG_T2, id) #create dataframe with raw scores

plotdattemp %>%
    reshape2::melt(by = "id") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= variable, y= value)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(group = id))
```

[image]

Model fit:

```
#Fit the Univariate Latent Change Score model
ULCS_DF<-'

COG_T2 ~ 1*COG_T1     # Fixed regression of COG_T2 on COG_T1
dCOG1 =~ 1*COG_T2     # Fixed regression of dCOG1 on COG_T2
COG_T2 ~ 0*1          # This line constrains the intercept of COG_T2 to 0
COG_T2 ~~ 0*COG_T2    # This fixes the variance of the COG_T2 to 0 

dCOG1 ~ 1             # This estimates the intercept of the change scores 
COG_T1 ~  1           # This estimates the intercept of COG_T1 
dCOG1 ~~  dCOG1       # This estimates the variance of the change scores 
COG_T1 ~~   COG_T1    # This estimates the variance of COG_T1 
dCOG1~COG_T1          # This estimates the self-feedback parameter

'

fitULCS <- lavaan(ULCS_DF, data=DF, estimator='mlr', fixed.x=FALSE, missing='fiml')
summary(ULCS_DF, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
```

But I am getting the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lav_mvnorm_missing_h1_estimate_moments(Y = X[[g]], wt = WT[[g]],  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    The smallest eigenvalue of the EM estimated variance-covariance
    matrix (Sigma) is smaller than 1e-05; this may cause numerical
    instabilities; interpret the results with caution.
```

Since the values are too small:

- How can I work around this? Should I be scaling the data around 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I don't think this will make your final result vary as much as to be consider not useful. Moreover, if you take a look at the warning, which is pretty accurate given the package you are using, it's only talking about 1 engine value over N2 that you are using.

Also, if you take a look at this post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219302/singularity-issues-in-gaussian-mixture-model

You will find a good explanation on the second comment of the winning answer. There you understand why the variance/covariance cannot be 0. In you particular case, the value is close to 0 and that is why you are getting a warning.

If you just want to get rid of the warning, one possibility would be scaling and the other normalizing. That is totally up to you.
when normalizing I would suggest a wide range, not 0...1 because you can face the same problem again.

Here are some code examples where I loaded your data in a variable called a:

```
> summary(a)
     COG_T1              COG_T2         
 Min.   :0.0009851   Min.   :0.0009951  
 1st Qu.:0.0010538   1st Qu.:0.0010594  
 Median :0.0010859   Median :0.0010716  
 Mean   :0.0010794   Mean   :0.0010759  
 3rd Qu.:0.0010990   3rd Qu.:0.0010989  
 Max.   :0.0011628   Max.   :0.0011411  
> summary(scale(a))
     COG_T1            COG_T2       
 Min.   :-2.6717   Min.   :-2.6149  
 1st Qu.:-0.7255   1st Qu.:-0.5352  
 Median : 0.1854   Median :-0.1387  
 Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   : 0.0000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.5573   3rd Qu.: 0.7439  
 Max.   : 2.3644   Max.   : 2.1092  
> summary((a-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a)))
     COG_T1           COG_T2       
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.05659  
 1st Qu.:0.3865   1st Qu.:0.41812  
 Median :0.5673   Median :0.48704  
 Mean   :0.5305   Mean   :0.51115  
 3rd Qu.:0.6412   3rd Qu.:0.64046  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :0.87780  
> summary((a-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a))+1)
     COG_T1          COG_T2     
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.057  
 1st Qu.:1.386   1st Qu.:1.418  
 Median :1.567   Median :1.487  
 Mean   :1.531   Mean   :1.511  
 3rd Qu.:1.641   3rd Qu.:1.640  
 Max.   :2.000   Max.   :1.878  
>
```

Edit: As the package got installed fast, here are the results using both normalize and scaling:

```
> fitULCS <- lavaan(ULCS_DF, data=scale(df), estimator='mlr', fixed.x=FALSE, missing='fiml')
> 
> summary(ULCS_DF, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character 
> 
> ULCS_DF
[1] "\n\nCOG_T2 ~ 1*COG_T1     # Fixed regression of COG_T2 on COG_T1\ndCOG1 =~ 1*COG_T2     # Fixed regression of dCOG1 on COG_T2\nCOG_T2 ~ 0*1          # This line constrains the intercept of COG_T2 to 0\nCOG_T2 ~~ 0*COG_T2    # This fixes the variance of the COG_T2 to 0 \n\ndCOG1 ~ 1             # This estimates the intercept of the change scores \nCOG_T1 ~  1           # This estimates the intercept of COG_T1 \ndCOG1 ~~  dCOG1       # This estimates the variance of the change scores \nCOG_T1 ~~   COG_T1    # This estimates the variance of COG_T1 \ndCOG1~COG_T1          # This estimates the self-feedback parameter\n\n"
> 
> normalize = function(a,x){
+   
+   ((a-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a)))+x
+   
+ }
> 
> fitULCS <- lavaan(ULCS_DF, data=normalize(df,1), estimator='mlr', fixed.x=FALSE, missing='fiml')
> 
> summary(ULCS_DF, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character 
> 
> ULCS_DF
[1] "\n\nCOG_T2 ~ 1*COG_T1     # Fixed regression of COG_T2 on COG_T1\ndCOG1 =~ 1*COG_T2     # Fixed regression of dCOG1 on COG_T2\nCOG_T2 ~ 0*1          # This line constrains the intercept of COG_T2 to 0\nCOG_T2 ~~ 0*COG_T2    # This fixes the variance of the COG_T2 to 0 \n\ndCOG1 ~ 1             # This estimates the intercept of the change scores \nCOG_T1 ~  1           # This estimates the intercept of COG_T1 \ndCOG1 ~~  dCOG1       # This estimates the variance of the change scores \nCOG_T1 ~~   COG_T1    # This estimates the variance of COG_T1 \ndCOG1~COG_T1          # This estimates the self-feedback parameter\n\n"
>
```

I only got the warning when running it alone, with no pre processing.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought when I looked at the data above was "those values look too small to detect any meaningful difference." The first chapter of the book "A First Course in Structural Equation Modeling" goes into why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. It's MRI data so the values in this case are very small by nature. If scaling to 1 doesn't alter the overall change and allows me to measure variance accurately then I think this will work. I'll leave the question open for now to see if there are other options to consider and select your answer tomorrow.